# How to modify the graphis curve

Tags: animation

[image]

I made a cycle animation. Is there any way can change the curve like what I drew?

Answer (score 2):

In the *Cycles* modifier, select *After Mode > Repeat with Offset*. But make sure that the last keyframe of your cycle is a bit lower on the Y axis otherwise it won't be visible:

[image]

Comment: sorry. I can't find Cycles modifier.

Comment: select the track you want on the left, then open the N panel (press N key)